# Is there some easy way to place the shape with coordinates?

Tags: diagrams, coordinates

I'm very to new to the latex so I may asking the stupid question.

I want to place a diagram of a cylinder at a position specified by coordinates.

I wonder that if such below codes exists.

```
\cylinder (coordinates of middle of the top circle)_(radius of the circle)_(height of the cylinder)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  See *Shape cylinder* on page 801, Ti*k*Z & PGF manual, version 3.1.8b. You need to define node with cylinder shape, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: I downloaded the manual.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the predefined cylinder node for that. `minimum height` and `minimum width` translate into height and twice the radius, respectively. You only need to shift the cylinder by the radius to have an effective anchor at the center of the top. You can adjust the `aspect` and so on.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path (0,0) node [cylinder, rotate=90, draw,anchor=before top,
        minimum height=2cm,%<- height
        minimum width=1cm,%<- radius
        yshift={0.5cm},%<- half of the radius
        ] {};
 \draw[stealth-] (0,0) -- ++ (1,2); % only to show that the placement works
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]